# Is there a better way to make a iso4217 RegEx?

Tags: regex, node.js

I have this right now:

```
^ADF|ADP|AED|AFA|AFN|ALL|AMD|ANG|AOA|AOK|AON|AOR|ARA|ARL|ARP|ARS|ATS|AUD|AWG|AZM|AZN|BAD|BAM|BBD|BDT|BEF|BGL|BGN|BHD|BIF|BMD|BND|BOB|BOP|BOV|BRB|BRC|BRE|BRL|BRN|BRR|BSD|BTN|BWP|BYB|BYN|BYR|BZD|CAD|CDF|CHE|CHF|CHW|CLE|CLF|CLP|CNY|COP|COU|CRC|CSD|CSK|CUC|CUP|CVE|CYP|CZK|DDM|DEM|DJF|DKK|DOP|DZD|ECS|ECV|EEK|EGP|ERN|ESA|ESB|ESP|ETB|EUR|FIM|FJD|FKP|FRF|GBP|GEL|GHC|GHS|GIP|GMD|GNE|GNF|GQE|GRD|GTQ|GWP|HKD|HNL|HRD|HRK|HTG|HUF|IDR|IEP|ILP|ILR|ILS|INR|IQD|IRR|ISJ|ISK|ITL|JMD|JOD|JPY|KES|KGS|KHR|KMF|KPW|KRW|KWD|KYD|KZT|LAK|LBP|LKR|LBP|LKR|LRD|LSL|LTL|LUF|LVL|LYD|MAD|MAF|MCF|MDL|MGA|MGF|MKD|MKN|MLV|MMK|MNT|MOP|MRO|MTL|MUR|MVQ|MVR|MWK|MXN|MXP|MXV|MYR|MZM|MZN|NAD|NGN|NIO|NLG|NOK|NPR|NZD|OMR|PAB|PEN|PGK|PHP|PKR|PLN|PTE|PYG|QAR|RON|RSD|RUB|RWF|SAR|SBD|SCR|SDG|SEK|SGD|SHP|SIT|SKK|SLL|SML|SOS|SRD|SSP|STD|SVC|SYP|SZL|THB|TJS|TMT|TND|TOP|TRY|TTD|TWD|TZS|UAH|UGX|USD|USN|UYI|UYU|UZS|VAL|VEF|VND|VUV|WST|XAF|XAG|XAU|XBA|XBB|XBC|XBD|XBT|XCD|XDR|XFU|XOK|XPD|XPF|XPT|XSU|XTS|XUA|YER|ZAR|ZMW|ZWL$
```

It works, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to go about it. I have some more codes to add as well so it will get longer. This RegEx will be used in Node as part of a JSON Schema for validation.

For validation they offer `pattern` that takes a RegEx.

Comment: Regex is not what you want, there's no really a "pattern" here. Consider having an external configuration that you'll compare against.

Comment: Are you sure a regex is the way to go? It seems... awkward

Comment: If this list changes your regex breaks... it might be easier to just use a list and iterate through the list programmatically, the cost will be about the same.

Comment: I guess you meant `^(HERE ALL THE ACRONYMS)$` (with parenthesis), otherwise the regex would match also `ACRC` et similia.

Comment: Well, even a shortened one - `^(A(D[FP]|[EMU]D|F[AN]|LL|[NW]G|O[AKNR]|R[ALPS]|TS|Z[MN])|B(A[DM]|[BSHMNZ]D|DT|[EI]F|G[LN]|O[BPV]|R[BCELNR]|TN|WP|Y[BNR])|C(AD|DF|H[EFW]|L[EFP]|NY|O[PU]|RC|S[DK]|U[CP]|VE|YP|ZK)|D([DE]M|JF|KK|OP|ZD)|E(C[SV]|EK|GP|RN|S[ABP]|TB|UR)|F(IM|JD|KP|RF)|G([BWI]P|EL|H[CS]|[MR]D|N[EF]|QE|TQ)|H(KD|NL|R[DK]|TG|UF)|I([DNR]R|EP|L[PRS]|QD|S[JK]|TL)|J([MO]D|PY)|K([EG]S|HR|MF|[PR]W|[WY]D|ZT)|L(AK|BP|KR|[RY]D|[STV]L|UF)|`

Comment: `M(A[DF]|CF|[DT]L|G[AF]|K[DN]|LV|[MW]K|NT|OP|RO|[UY]R|V[QR]|X[NPV]|Z[MN])|N([AZ]D|GN|IO|LG|OK|PR)|O(MR|AB)|P([EL]N|GK|HP|KR|TE|YG)|QAR|R(ON|SD|UB|WF)|S([AC]R|[BGR]D|DG|[EK]K|HP|IT|[LMZ]L|OS|[SY]P|TD|VC)|T(HB|[JZ]S|MT|[NWT]D|OP|RY)|UAH|U(GX|S[DN]|Y[IU]|ZS)|V(AL|EF|ND|UV)|WST|X(A[FGU]|B[ABCDT]|CD|DR|[FS]U|OK|P[DFT]|TS|UA)|YER|Z(AR|MW|WL))$` is too long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var test = "ABC";
words = ["ADF", "ADP", ...]
if (words.includes(test)){
  return true;
}
```

Doing this with a regex makes no sense.